# Как по долгому нажатию на карту выставить маркер?

Tags: android, google-maps-api

И можно ли считать координаты этого маркера?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final GoogleMap googleMap;

googleMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onMapLongClick(final LatLng latLng)
            {
                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng));
            }
        });
```

Для дополнительной информации: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/interactivity